# Am I right? I don't know the answer I wrote is right or wrong. (SQL)assignment

Tags: sql

For each department headed by a female manager, list the department name, and the number of employees who work for that department.

My Answer:

```
SELECT E.SEX
FROM EMPLOYEE AS E
WHERE E.Ssn IN (SELECT Essn
                FROM DEPENDENT AS D
                WHERE E.Sex = D.Sex);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coF4S.png)

Comment: You're only returning one column. Clearly not right. And dependents have nothing to do with it nor do matching genders.

Comment: What answer do you get when you run this? Does it look like it answers the question? Maybe check the data by hand, what do *you* think the answer should be (and does it match your query results)?

Comment: Hi @shawnt00 , thanks for answering my question, may I ask you how can I find more basic sql tutorials , in facts i don't know how to do that(assignment) , and our teacher ask us to do that.

Comment: When asking SQL questions, a [mcve] is a great start!

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is probably wrong. My solution is below:

```
select aa.name,
count(*) as cnt

(select a.dname
,dnumber 

from department as a 

inner join employee as b
on a.mgr_ssn = b.ssn

where a.sex = female
) as aa

inner join empoyee as bb
on aa.dnumber = bb.dno

group by aa.name
```

The logic is following:

1, find all departments which are headed by a female manager. the code is follwing

```
select a.dname
,dnumber 

from department as a 

inner join employee as b
on a.mgr_ssn = b.ssn

where a.sex = female
```

2, group by the department name and count the number of employees who work for that department.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to study up on it inner joins, aliases/correlation names, and groups/aggregates.

```
select d.dname, count(*)
from dept d inner join emp em on em.ssn = dept.mgr_ssn
inner join emp e on e.dno = d.dnumber
where em.sex = 'F'
group by d.dname
```